# Arquillian integrations tests - cannot run test, when other instance of wildfly is running

Tags: java, integration-testing, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

like in the question. When i have running wildfly instance, then i can't run my integration tests with it.
Same if i point to 2 different server locations.

arquillan:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <container qualifier="wildfly" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">${jboss.home}</property>
            <property name="modulePath">${module.path}</property>
            <property name="outputToConsole">true</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

Error:

```
    Could not invoke start on: org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl@2b175c00
    org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException
        at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.embedded.EmbeddedDeployableContainer.startInternal(EmbeddedDeployableContainer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.start(CommonDeployableContainer.java:123)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:199)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:163)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:157)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:77)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:70)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachSuiteContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:221)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startSuiteContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:86)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:75)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEMB0022: Cannot invoke 'start' on embedded process
        at org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl.invokeOnServer(EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl.java:93)
        at org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl.start(EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl.java:55)
        at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.embedded.EmbeddedDeployableContainer.startInternal(EmbeddedDeployableContainer.java:60)
        ... 68 more
    Caused by: org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedProcessStartException: WFLYEMB0021: Cannot start embedded process
        at org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedStandaloneServerFactory$StandaloneServerImpl.start(EmbeddedStandaloneServerFactory.java:320)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl.invokeOnServer(EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl.java:81)
        ... 70 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Operation failed
        at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.operationFailed(AsyncFutureTask.java:74)
        at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.get(AsyncFutureTask.java:268)
        at org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedStandaloneServerFactory$StandaloneServerImpl.start(EmbeddedStandaloneServerFactory.java:301)
        ... 75 more
    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
        at org.

jboss.as.server.BootstrapListener.bootFailure(BootstrapListener.java:87)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:417)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:370)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Anyone can help me with it?
My pom contains jboss.home property.
I don't know what can cause error here.

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>java.util.logging.manager</name>
                            <value>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <jboss.home>${jboss.home}</jboss.home>
                        <module.path>${jboss.home}/modules</module.path>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Maybe there are any others newer technology? How can i test bean without arquillian?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that something like:

```
<argLine>-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100</argLine>
```

added to the configuration section would do.  This would run Wildfly with all ports offset by 100.

Comment: @Razikus Did you find the solution ? I am facing the same problem

Comment: @MichalHeneš hey, i found workaround - there is a possibility to deploy it to running wildfly by management console. Look at my source here https://github.com/Razikus/Casino-server/blob/master/src/test/resources/arquillian.xml You have also to add management user with add-user.sh script.